c++ dll loading: Call function before global variable constructors
I'm working on a plugin based system that uses shared libraries for the plugins. I want to set up some static variables in these libraries so I can use them in various places, including global constructors. Can I call a function from my main executable in a shared library to run before my global constructors in said shared library? Whether I use shared memory or I register static variables by passing them to the shared library, this set up code would otherwise happen after global constructors within the dll.
For further context, some use-cases are: loggers, allocators, and console variables/cvars. These systems all are used pervasively across the program and I want to be able to use static variables from these global constructors. In particular, AutoCvars are a common use case where a specific "variable" can be used from a file, and for simplicity, it is placed in the global space so it can grab the data immediately, and live through the lifetime of the application:  https://vkguide.dev/docs/extra-chapter/cvar_system/
Here's a code example:
Allocator.hpp
#pragma once

class Allocator {
public:
    static Allocator* GetAllocator();
    static void SetAllocator(Allocator* allocator);

    void* Allocate(size_t size);
    size_t GetUsedSize() const;

protected:
    static Allocator allocatorSingleton;
    size_t usedSize = 0;
};

Allocator.cpp:
#include "Allocator.hpp"

static Allocator* allocatorState = nullptr;

Allocator* Allocator::GetAllocator() {
    return allocatorState;
}

void Allocator::SetAllocator(Allocator* allocator) {
    allocatorState = allocator;
}

void* Allocator::Allocate(size_t size) {
    // ALLOCATION OCCURS HERE
    usedSize += size;

    return nullptr;
}

size_t Allocator::GetUsedSize() const {
    return usedSize;
}


Main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Allocator.hpp"

int main() {
    Allocator allocator;
    Allocator::SetAllocator(&allocator);

    HINSTANCE dllHandle = LoadLibrary(L"Library.dll");
    if (!dllHandle) {
        printf("Could not load the dynamic library.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Allocated Size Before: %zu.\n", allocator.GetUsedSize());
    auto fn = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(Allocator*)>(GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "RegisterAllocator"));
    if (!fn) {
        printf("Could not locate the function.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fn(&allocator);
    printf("Allocated Size After: %zu.\n", allocator.GetUsedSize());

    return 0;
}

DllMain.cpp:
#include "../CVarTest/Allocator.hpp"

class SampleClass {
public:
    SampleClass() {
        Allocator::GetAllocator()->Allocate(42);
    }
};

// Here, SampleClass doesn't work, and causes an error. This is what I want to get working.
SampleClass myInstance;

extern "C" {
    void __declspec(dllexport) RegisterAllocator(Allocator* sourceAllocator) {
        Allocator::SetAllocator(sourceAllocator);

        // Here, SampleClass does work, and the final usedSize is 42.
        // SampleClass myInstance;
    }
}


can you put the question in the form here is a library function that calls X function and is called from function Y and here is the main file that calls Y function and i want Z function to be called before X or Y, something like that will make the question clear to the readers.

No you don't want to set static variables, if you want your plugin dll's to do logging etc. You want to use dependency injection from your executable e.g. the exe will create those objects and you inject references to them (ideally abstract baseclasses/interfaces).  In other words relying on globals is just asking for problems and it is not a recommended design approach.

you can call it, if set LdrRegisterDllNotification and call this functions from callback. but in this case, result can be undefined, if function use some global data, initialized in dll entry point. so in general - this is wrong solution

@AhmedAEK alright I'll work on a minimal example.

@PepijnKramer I am using dependency injection in a sense - currently I'm creating a logger and allocator in my core exe and sending a "PluginInterface" to my plugins so they can register the logger and allocator as static variables that I can use as a singleton. I tend to avoid singletons but in cases that are used so frequently, such as loggers, allocators, etc, passing references around can get cumbersome. I want to set these static variables before Global Constructors can be called.

Do not tag C for C++ questions.

not exactly portable but on windows you can have a dll lookup an exported function from the executable Correct way to access functions defined in .exe from .dll (see the answer with GetProcAddress),  you can abuse meyer's singleton in each dll to load a function from the executable and use it in the dll, the equivalent on linux is that you will have to abuse the fact that the symbol table only uses the first exported symbol of a specific name, and your executable will get loaded first into the symbol table

note that static initialization has no order, and it is not thread-safe, so Allocator::SetAllocator(&allocator); will be racing with the static constructor in your dll .... you need to use SetAllocator before you use LoadLibrary, also your allocator has to be thread-safe because it is not guaranteed that static initialization happens within the main thread.

note that if you apply the answer and use a resource locator pattern, you still have a race condition, because again initialization of globals is not thread-safe, and may not happen on the main thread, so calling SetAllocator in your main will race with anyone that is trying to use GetAllocator in the global scope, unless it happens before LoadLibrary

@AhmedAEK I made a mistake in the example of putting SetAllocator after LoadLibrary. I have edited it to fix it. In this case, in the main executable module, the allocator variable will have been set when the DLL is loaded, and race conditions shouldn't be a problem. The idea of using a function from main is interesting, and I may use that. I'm also going to evaluate RbMm's suggestion of LdrRegisterDllNotification

Both answers from @RbMm and @AhmedAEK seemed to work well. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions. I believe I'll use Method 2, as it seems cleaner. Here are code examples of each:
Method 1: LdrRegisterDllNotification from @RbMm
This method uses DLL loading callbacks from ntdll.dll to call methods in the new libraries. It seems like there may be some vulnerabilities here in case you're not careful, and will likely require more thorough investigation.
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Allocator.hpp"

typedef struct _UNICODE_STR
{
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR pBuffer;
} UNICODE_STR, * PUNICODE_STR;

// Sources:
// https://shorsec.io/blog/dll-notification-injection/
// https://modexp.wordpress.com/2020/08/06/windows-data-structures-and-callbacks-part-1/

typedef struct _LDR_DLL_LOADED_NOTIFICATION_DATA {
    ULONG           Flags;             // Reserved.
    PUNICODE_STR FullDllName;       // The full path name of the DLL module.
    PUNICODE_STR BaseDllName;       // The base file name of the DLL module.
    PVOID           DllBase;           // A pointer to the base address for the DLL in memory.
    ULONG           SizeOfImage;       // The size of the DLL image, in bytes.
} LDR_DLL_LOADED_NOTIFICATION_DATA, * PLDR_DLL_LOADED_NOTIFICATION_DATA;

typedef struct _LDR_DLL_UNLOADED_NOTIFICATION_DATA {
    ULONG           Flags;             // Reserved.
    PUNICODE_STR FullDllName;       // The full path name of the DLL module.
    PUNICODE_STR BaseDllName;       // The base file name of the DLL module.
    PVOID           DllBase;           // A pointer to the base address for the DLL in memory.
    ULONG           SizeOfImage;       // The size of the DLL image, in bytes.
} LDR_DLL_UNLOADED_NOTIFICATION_DATA, * PLDR_DLL_UNLOADED_NOTIFICATION_DATA;

typedef union _LDR_DLL_NOTIFICATION_DATA {
    LDR_DLL_LOADED_NOTIFICATION_DATA   Loaded;
    LDR_DLL_UNLOADED_NOTIFICATION_DATA Unloaded;
} LDR_DLL_NOTIFICATION_DATA, * PLDR_DLL_NOTIFICATION_DATA;

typedef VOID(CALLBACK* PLDR_DLL_NOTIFICATION_FUNCTION)(
    ULONG                       NotificationReason,
    PLDR_DLL_NOTIFICATION_DATA  NotificationData,
    PVOID                       Context);

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* _LdrRegisterDllNotification) (
    ULONG                          Flags,
    PLDR_DLL_NOTIFICATION_FUNCTION NotificationFunction,
    PVOID                          Context,
    PVOID* Cookie);

VOID MyCallback(ULONG NotificationReason, const PLDR_DLL_NOTIFICATION_DATA NotificationData, PVOID Context) {
    if (lstrcmpiW(NotificationData->Loaded.BaseDllName->pBuffer, L"Library.dll") != 0) {
        return;
    }

    HINSTANCE dllHandle = reinterpret_cast<HINSTANCE>(NotificationData->Loaded.DllBase);
    auto fn = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(Allocator*)>(GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "RegisterAllocator"));
    if (!fn) {
        printf("Could not locate the function.\n");
        return;
    }

    fn(Allocator::GetAllocator());
}

int main() {
    Allocator allocator;
    Allocator::SetAllocator(&allocator);

    HMODULE hNtdll = GetModuleHandleA("NTDLL.dll");

    if (hNtdll != NULL) {
        _LdrRegisterDllNotification pLdrRegisterDllNotification = (_LdrRegisterDllNotification)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "LdrRegisterDllNotification");

        PVOID cookie;
        NTSTATUS status = pLdrRegisterDllNotification(0, (PLDR_DLL_NOTIFICATION_FUNCTION)MyCallback, NULL, &cookie);
        if (status != 0) {
            printf("Failed to load DLL Callback! Exiting\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Failed to load NTDLL.dll! Exiting\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Allocated Size Before: %zu.\n", allocator.GetUsedSize());
    HINSTANCE dllHandle = LoadLibrary(L"Library.dll");
    if (!dllHandle) {
        printf("Could not load the dynamic library.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Allocated Size After: %zu.\n", allocator.GetUsedSize());

    return 0;
}

Method 2: Getting the variable from a Singleton's Getter from @AhmedAEK
This alteration to Allocator.cpp uses the Getter of the Singleton to find its value in the main executable if it is not yet set. I use GetModuleHandle(NULL) to get the main module, and find the ProcAddress of a non-member function that will return the singleton's value.
// ...

#if MAIN_EXECUTABLE
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) Allocator* GetAllocator() {
        return Allocator::GetAllocator();
    }
}

Allocator* Allocator::GetAllocator() {
    return allocatorState;
}
#else
#include <Windows.h>

Allocator* Allocator::GetAllocator() {
    if (allocatorState == nullptr) {
        HMODULE module = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        auto GetAllocatorFn = (Allocator*(*)(void))GetProcAddress(module, "GetAllocator");
        if (GetAllocatorFn != NULL) {
            return GetAllocatorFn();
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    return allocatorState;
}
#endif


As others mentioned, the way your are trying to do it is probably wrong.
I worked  with DLLs before, loading dynamic plugins as you are doing. One solution I've found to do something as you're asking, is to have a common dependency.
+-------------+
|    Main     |
| Application +----- Load DLL ---+
|    (.exe)   |                  |
+-----+-------+                  v
      |                    +-----------+
      v                    |           |
+-------------+      +-----+ My Plugin |
|             |      |     |           |
|    Utils    |<-----+     +-----------+
|    (.dll)   |
+-------------+

Now, "Utils" can include the necessary tools: classes, globals, etc. that you want to use in "My Plugin" as well as in your "Main Application". This works great since "Utils" will already be loaded when the plugin gets loaded and its globals initialized as expected at the time you load "My Plugin".
(i.e. a dependency gets loaded only once even if required by multiple DLLs or plugins.)

The issue isn't creating instances of classes or loading specific code - the issue is accessing data globally - specifically through singletons or other static member variables. The Utils class idea is useful and something I already considered before - but it doesn't answer the question about how to access the static member variables before global constructors can run. You may dislike global variables or constructors, but they are a tool heavily used in C++. There's specific cases where I find them useful and I want to know if I can use global constructors with static member variables in DLLS.

Why would it not work for you to place those global variables in Utils.dll? Then when you load your plugin, those variables are ready for use. In this way, you can even use smart pointers so you don't have to bother with all the memory management. So your constructors inside your DLL just need to be aware of the global variables in the Utils.dll (as in my example above). You would thus define those variables in a header such as Utils.h. And I do use singletons, although a static var is not useful. I use globals.

It would work to place them in Utils.dll, and I'm likely to start using a Utils class in the future, but the question of where it's placed is not very important. Getting those variables without passing them explicitly to the constructors is what I was concerned with. They can be globals, static variables, but how do I grab that? RbMm's suggestion of using notifications to setup the variables' instance in the DLL, or Ahmed's suggestion of using GetProcAddress within the singleton getter, both grab that data. This is important because each module has their own instance of the global variable.
